# Regular expression to match a string which is NOT matched by a given regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I've been hoving around by some answers here, and I can't find a solution to my problem:

I have this regexp which matches everyting inside an HTML span tag, including contents:

```
<span\b[^>]*>(.*?)</span>
```

and I want to find a way to make a search in all the text, except for what is matched with that regexp.
For example, if my text is:

```
var text = "...for there is a class of <span class="highlight">guinea</span> pigs which..."
```

... then the regexp would match:

```
<span class="highlight">guinea</span>
```

and I want to be able to make a regexp such that if I search for "class", regexp will match  `"...for there is a class of..."` 
and will not match inside the tag, like in

```
"... class="highlight"..."
```

The word to be matched ("class") might be anywhere within the text. I've tried

```
(?!<span\b[^>]*>(.*?)</span>)class
```

but it keeps searching inside tags as well.
I want to find a solution using only regexp, not dealing with DOM nor JQuery. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You can't do that. Instead, do the search on individual text nodes in the DOM.

Comment: @Nit: I understand this is for fair complex and arbitrary HTML. Mine is as simple and predictable as the one I posted. Thank you though.

Comment: @ torazaburo: Not the same case. I just need to avoid tags like the one I posted, not some tags yes and some not :). I don't know apeshiagt about DOM and I thought that searching in the complement of a well-defined set would do the trick, but apparently I'm touching sensitive cords here ;). There there. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Although I wouldn't recommend this, I would do something like below

`(class)(?:(?=.*<span\b[^>]*>))|(?:(?<=<\/span>).*)(class)`

You can see this in action here

[Rubular Link for this regex](http://rubular.com/r/KJRS7MqbVW)

You can capture your matches from the groups and work with them as needed. If you can, use a HTML parser and then find matches from the text element.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but if I get you right, this should do what you wan't. It's done with a single RegEx but js can't (to my knowledge) extract the result without joining the results in a loop.

The RegEx: `/(?:<span\b[^>]*>.*?<\/span>)|(.)/g`

Example js code:

```
var str = '...for there is a class of <span class="highlight">guinea</span> pigs which...',
    pattern = /(?:<span\b[^>]*>.*?<\/span>)|(.)/g,
    match,
    res = '';


match = pattern.exec(str)
while( match != null )
{
    res += match[1];
    match = pattern.exec(str)
}

document.writeln('Result:' + res);
```

In English: Do a non capturing test against your tag-expression **or** capture any character. Do this globally to get the entire string. The result is a capture group for each character in your string, **except** the tag. As pointed out, this is ugly - can result in a serious number of capture groups - but gets the job done.

If you need to send it in and retrieve the result in one call, I'd have to agree with previous contributors - It can't be done!